# Парсинг файла на Java

Tags: java

Все нужно сделать с помощью Scanner.
Есть файл. Первая строчка France.
Вторая строчка ParisRussia
Между Paris и Russia стоит символ с кодом 6, и это нужно прочитать как целое 6.
Задача прочитать Paris в String. Потом прочитать 6 в целое.
Russia нужно прочитать на следующем шаге цикла - относится к другой записи.

```
scanner.next("[a-zA-z]*");
```

InputMismatchException.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (scanner.hasNext()) {
scanner.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]+");
line = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(line);

 line = scanner.next();
System.out.println(line);
scanner.useDelimiter("[A-Za-z]+");
 line = scanner.next();
for (char c : line.toCharArray()) {
int i = c;
if (i<32)
System.out.println(i);
}
} //while
```